# why this program returns an IOExecption?

Tags: java

please i have a problem in this program its returns to me an IOExeption I'm working with net-beans I tested many times and i found that the problem is in 
`fichier=new FileWriter("../test.txt",true);`

here is the code source:
I guess it will not appear in IDE but if we make the .exe using for example Excesior JET http://www.excelsiorjet.com/ you will find that there is an exception IO. I try to correct it but I didnt find the problem exactly the FileWriter syntax is correct and I closed the file at the end

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package te;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Khalid
 */
public class Fenetre extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form Fenetre
     */
    FileWriter fichier;
    public Fenetre() {
        initComponents();

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("implanter");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(158, 158, 158)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addContainerGap(165, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 41, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(248, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
             String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306";
             Connection conn = (Connection)DriverManager.getConnection(url,"root","");
             Statement state=conn.createStatement();
             ResultSet r=state.executeQuery("select NOW()");
         fichier= new FileWriter("../test.txt",true);
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"test 1 après new filewriter");
            if(r.next()){
         fichier.write(jButton1.getActionCommand()+": "+" test "+" Date: "+r.getString(1)+"\r\n");
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"test 1 après write");
            fichier.flush();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"test 1 après flush");

            }
            fichier.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"test 1 après close");
            conn.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erreur IOEXCEPTION");
        }


        catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erreur SQLEXCE");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erreur classnotfound");
        } 
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    // End of variables declaration
}
```

Comment: How is `jButton1` relevant to the problem? Please only post relevant code. If you get an exception, post the stack trace.

Comment: Can you post the message of the exception? IOException is too general!

Comment: You should look at getting the text as a resource not as a file. Please search this site for similar questions to see the details.

Comment: From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29): an `IOException` is thrown _"if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason"_.

Comment: First thank you for these comments. about this exception that i get. I doesnot exist when i test in netbeans but only in the .exe that I make by excelsior jet. i dont have any idea about the exception i cant post it because i dont get it in the IDE only in .exe when i start the .exe i click the button automatically i receive the window of JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"erreur IOEXCEPTION");

Comment: what do You think about my problem ? best regards

Comment: FileWriter creates a file if doesnt exist and if it exists it addes to the file as the second argument represents. thanks Ted Hopp

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem if someone has the same as me.
Check the file that is create, its created on the same folder where they are OS folders like for windows 7 so, here in this part we cant add something ; open file for writing, create file, ... (access denied ) for these operation we must have the root privileges